# Firefox headless not working within Docker as non-root user

Tags: docker, firefox, playwright, firefox-headless

As the title says, I'm having trouble running Firefox in headless mode inside a Docker container as a non-root user. Consider the following Dockerfile, built with `docker build -t firefox .`

```
FROM python:3.8-buster
RUN apt-get update -qq \
    && apt-get install -qy \
        libappindicator1 \
        libasound2 \
        libatk1.0-0 \
        libc6 \
        libcairo2 \
        libcups2 \
        libdbus-1-3 \
        libexpat1 \
        libfontconfig1 \
        libgbm-dev \
        libgcc1 \
        libgconf-2-4 \
        libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 \
        libglib2.0-0 \
        libgtk-3-0 \
        libnspr4 \
        libnss3 \
        libpango-1.0-0 \
        libpangocairo-1.0-0 \
        libpci-dev \
        libstdc++6 \
        libx11-6 \
        libx11-xcb1 \
        libxcb1 \
        libxcomposite1 \
        libxcursor1 \
        libxdamage1 \
        libxext6 \
        libxfixes3 \
        libxi6 \
        libxrandr2 \
        libxrender1 \
        libxss1 \
        libxtst6 \
        xdg-utils \
        nano

RUN wget https://download-installer.cdn.mozilla.net/pub/firefox/releases/85.0.2/linux-x86_64/en-US/firefox-85.0.2.tar.bz2 -O /firefox.tar.bz2
RUN tar -xf /firefox.tar.bz2 --directory /
WORKDIR /firefox
RUN ./firefox -CreateProfile "headless /profile-headless" -headless
RUN chmod -Rf 777 /firefox && chmod -Rf 777 /profile-headless
cmd ["./firefox", "-profile", "/profile-headless", "-headless", "--screenshot", "https://example.org"]
```

If I run a container as root, all is good and the process finishes (a few warnings appear, but it works overall):

```
$ docker run --rm firefox
*** You are running in headless mode.
[GFX1-]: glxtest: Unable to open a connection to the X server
[GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL missing
$
```

However, if I run it as a different user, the same output appears, but the process hangs.

```
$ docker run --rm --user=1001 firefox
*** You are running in headless mode.
[GFX1-]: glxtest: Unable to open a connection to the X server
[GFX1-]: glxtest: libEGL missing
```

I tried assigning 777 permissions to both the directory that holds the binaries (`/firefox`) and the profile one (`profile-headless`), that doesn't seem to work.
Probably some dependencies are not necessary, I just didn't want to spend time on that while I have bigger issues.

As a note, I initially encountered this while trying to run `playwright-python` inside Docker as non-root. The Chromium browser works just fine, but Firefox fails to initialize and `playwright` ends up throwing a timeout error. I dug deeper and realized that standalone Firefox was failing for me as well.

I suppose I must be missing some configuration, env variables or such. Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Playwright does use its own version of Firefox and WebKit. For that a specific Playwright build is required so the normal Firefox or Safari can't be used there which you are trying to install via `apt`.

In your scenario, you are probably looking for the command to automatically install the dependencies, which can get done by executing `npx playwright install-deps`, see [here](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/cli/#install-system-dependencies) for reference.

Besides that it's recommended to use [official Docker image](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/docker), which is tested for every release and ensured that it contains all the necessary dependencies to run Playwright with all its features.

Comment: The Playwright part is pure anecdote, it's not even present in the Dockerfile. The question is about running Firefox within docker as a non-root user.

Comment: You can leverage the official Docker image which has already a non-root user available "pwuser". See here: https://playwright.dev/docs/docker#crawling-and-scraping. Are you using Playwright? If not, I would recommend to remove the tag since my comment is also then irrelevant. The error `Unable to open a connection to the X server` comes from that you launch firefox in normal headed mode. Use either xvfb-run or the headless mode to fix this.